# What is the algorithm for solving this problem?

Tags: python, algorithm

We have a row of X nests and we have Y birds. Every bird has a nest. Birds do not like each other and want to sit in their nests as far away from other birds and at the ends of the row as possible. Since the bird is sitting in the nest, it no longer moves. Birds come to the nests one by one. Need to find how many free nests to the right and left of the last bird.

For example, if we have 10 nests and 1 bird:
Answer: (4, 5)
10 nests and 2 birds: (1, 3)
10 nests and 3 birds: (2, 1), etc.
The number of nests may be about 5 000 000 000.

My try is:

```
def rec(x, y):
y -= 1
z = x // 2
print('y =', y)
if y == 0:
    if z % 2 == 0:
        return x - z - 1, x - z
    elif z % 2 != 0:
        return x-z, x-z
if z == 4:
    return 1, 2
elif z == 3:
    return 1, 1
else:
    return rec(z, y)
```

But I cannot take into account the fact that, for example, if there are 17 nests, then the third bird will sit on the nest to the right of the first, and not between the first and second.

Comment: I think I may be a bit confused with the parameters for the algorithm. I'm sorry but I don't see how if there are 10 nests and only a single bird, how we'd know where that single bird would choose. Like could (9,0) be a possibility, or does it have to be (4,5)?

Comment: "Birds do not like each other and want to sit in their nests as far away from other birds and at the ends of the row as possible" - it means, that bird will choose middle of free nests every time. If 10 nest are free, we will count it like 4 on the left and 5 on the right.

Comment: @OstenGibson, (9,0) wouldn't work, because the birds dislike the ends of the row as well - but it could just as easily be (5,4) as (4,5), it seems there is some rule for tie-breaking that was left out of the description.  And (1,3) for the 2-bird scenario makes no sense, presumably the second bird would go to the middle of the run of 5 nests, making the answer (2,2).

Comment: @jasonharper, i suppose, that it doesn't matter if it will be (5,4) or (4,5) initially, because an answer will be the same (apparently).

Comment: Ah sorry yes the wording confused me there a bit. The ands crushed my brain. And yes as @jasonharper the two bird scenario is also peculiar.

Comment: I'm sorry you state that, "but I cannot take into account the fact that, for example, if there are 17 nests, then the third bird will sit on the nest to the right of the first, and not between the first and second." But in that scenario we imagine bird 1 sitting at nest 9. Bird two lands at nest 4 or 5. Bird 3 would have to land in nest 13 or 14 to fill the parameters correct? It wouldn't make sense for bird 3 to land in 6 or 7 as there's more space elsewhere.

Comment: Also the provided code wouldn't currently work either correct. As for example 10 nests and 1 bird, wouldn't (5,5) be returned as z = 5, x = 10, and y = 0.

Comment: @osten-gibson, under the impossibility of taking into account i mean implementing into programming code. If we have 17 nests, 1st is on 9th nest, 2nd is on 4th nest, 3rd is on 13th place, 4th is on 7th nest, 5th is on 15th nest, 6th is on 2nd nest and 7th is on 11th nest. And that's all, there is no free nest, which not near edge or another taken nest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @jasonharper pointed out, the statement for the 2 bird scenario is not correct (using common logic). If the objective is what you described, then a solution is presented below:

```py
nests = 17
birds = 3

free = [(1, nests)]
for b in range(birds):
  t = max(free, key = lambda p: abs(p[1] - p[0]))
  break_point = (t[0]+t[1])//2
  free.remove(t)
  free.append((t[0], break_point-1))
  free.append((break_point+1, t[1]))

left, right = free[-2], free[-1]
answer = (left[1]-left[0]+1, right[1]-right[0]+1)
print(answer)
```

**Explanation**

The list `free` stores tuples, denoting the different ranges (starting from 1) of nests that are empty (it's a union of the ranges of empty nests).

In each iteration, we select the widest range, we remove it from the list, we brake it in the middle and we append the two resultant ranges to the end of the list. After all the birds are placed, we select the last two ranges in the list (since we are interested only in the last bird) and we print the desired result.

This is quite possibly **not** the fastest, nor the most memory efficient solution. It just displays the logic behind the problem in a readable way.